# Database accesses one variable correctly, but not the other

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, mobile

So I have two variables that I am currently trying to access. waterAmt and bucketExp. I am not certain why the waterAmt variable is working correctly but the other is not. It seems that bucketExp is not being stored the way it should, even though it is being stored the same was as waterAmt. thanks in advance for the help.

Code for accessing the database:

```
//pull data
data = new Database(SetupTimerPC1.this);
data.open();
bucketExpTotal = data.getBucketExp();
totalWater = data.getWaterAmt();
data.close();

//add new data to old
bucketExpTotal += bucketExp;
totalWater += waterAmt;

//push data
data.open();
data.bucketExpEntry(bucketExpTotal);
data.waterAmountEntry(totalWater);
data.close();
```

Code for entering waterAmt into database:

```
public long waterAmountEntry(int waterAmt)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_WATER, waterAmt);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}//end waterAmountEntry function
```

Code for entering bucketExp into database:

```
public long bucketExpEntry(int bucketExp)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_BUCKETEXP, bucketExp);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}//end bucketExpEntry function
```

Code for pulling waterAmt from database:

```
public int getWaterAmt() 
{
    int waterAmount = 0, iWaterAmount = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
            KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
            KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {   
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
        {
            iWaterAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WATER);
            waterAmount = c.getInt(iWaterAmount);
        }//end for
        c.close();
        return waterAmount;
    }//end if
    return 0;
}//end getWaterAmt function
```

code for pulling bucketExp from database:

```
public int getBucketExp() 
{
    int bucketExp = 0, iBucketExp = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK, KEY_WATER,
            KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE, KEY_SHOVELEXP,
            KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
        {
            iBucketExp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUCKETEXP);
            bucketExp = c.getInt(iBucketExp);
        }//end for
        c.close();
        return bucketExp;
    }//end if
    return 0;
}//end getBucketExp function
```

Comment: In both of your `get` methods you are looping over the entire cursor and returning the value for the last result. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Oh no that's not what I meant to do. I just want each variable to be able to access it's own value that has been stored and to save its own value. Any idea what to do different? Sorry, I am new to android and SQLite and I appreciate your help.

Comment: How many rows is that table supposed to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your query amounts to this:

```
"SELECT [columns] FROM [table];"
```

This returns all the rows in your table. Next you are iterating over the entire set of results, and in each iteration you set the value to return equal to some column in the result row.

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) { 
    bucketExp = cursor.getInt(...);
}
```

Essentially this means `bucketExp` will equal the value of this column from the very last row in the results.

What I ***think*** you want is the value for a particular row/record. You need to change your query to return just the row you are looking for, and get rid of the `for` loop. Here's an example that will look up a specific row by an ID and return bucketExp:

```
public int getBucketExp(long id) {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_BUCKETEXP };
    String where = KEY_ROWID + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Long.toString(id) };

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, where, whereArgs,
            null, null, null);

    int bucketExp = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        bucketExp = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUCKETEXP));
    }

    return bucketExp;
}
```

Comment: There is only one row so I do not need to worry about filtering out the rows. I tried to go off of your example but it is not returning anything. What is it that you are saying I should include after the "KEY_ROWID" in your String called where?

Comment: Also when I change my code to something like the example in my getWaterAmt function, I no longer get the correct amounts there either.

Comment: "There is only one row" -- The code you have posted in your question uses `SQLiteDatabase.insert`, so you are doing an INSERT and not an UPDATE. Every call to `waterAmountEnty` or `bucketExpEntry` will create a new row. Use `SQLiteDatabase.update` if that's not what you intended. The `where` string is supposed to have the question mark. The question marks will be replaced by the arguments in `whereArgs`, in order. In this case I've set it up to take a known row ID and use that for the WHERE clause because I assumed (based on your post) that you had multiple rows.